# Is it possible to transfer university midway through the first month of university?

Tags: application, international-students, canada, transfer-student

I'm a university student in Ontario Canada. For personal reasons, I am looking to move to another university right now (ASAP). I'm a second-year student on my 3rd day of classes. Which U I will move to idk.

Question: Is it possible to transfer to another university in Canada, at this point? If so, how?

*Undergraduate*

Comment: Is this undergraduate or postgraduate (coursework or research)?

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus UnderGrad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *apply* to another institution but you are kinda late for the Fall term since they must be nearing the date beyond which courses cannot be added and you’ve not even started the admission process.  In the short term nothing to do (unless you choose to  withdraw and get some tuition back, if possible).

You might be able to apply for a Winter term admission depending on the program, and get *some* transfer credits, but that would be specific to each program.

Comment: Ok, this was my hunch.